# Romans 10:19 and Psalm 19:4: “voice” or “line”?

Tags: romans

Many references indicate that Paul is quoting Psalm 19:4 when he writes in Romans 10:18 “Their voice … “ (Strong’s 5353). However, the Hebrew noun in Psalm 19:4 (Strong’s 6957) seems to always be translated “line”. Is Paul indicating a line of reasoning, or proof? Or is there history there that is not readily indicated to the lay reader? Do most scholars attribute Paul’s quote to Psalm 19:4?

Comment: This would be better on [hermeneutics.se].

Comment: related on BHSE: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/does-paul-allude-to-the-context-of-psalm-194-in-romans-1018 and https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/17329/voice-or-string-in-psalm-194